# Why are file managers not using top-dir trash dirs?

Tags: python, fuse, dolphin, trash, pcmanfm

I'm making a FUSE filesystem with fusepy and I want to give a special meaning to deletion. I'd like to intercept moves to trash too. For this I would like file managers to use the trash dirs at the root/mount point of my filesystem (`.Trash/$uid` or `.Trash-$uid`) rather than the user ones (`~/.local/share/Trash`).

I'm referring to the [Freedesktop Trash specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html).

I've tried 3 file managers:

- PCManFM-Qt uses the top-dir trash dir ;
- PCManFM tells me the filesystem doesn't support Trash and offers a hard delete ;
- Dolphin creates the top-dir trash dir if it doesn't exist but then uses the user one.

Can I convince all file managers to use `.Trash/$uid` / `.Trash-$uid`?

Comment: All three file managers are opensource, free to modify.

Comment: I have set up a `.Trash` directory on a 2nd HDD and in a `tmpfs` directory. Dolphin uses the one on the HDD but not the one in the `tmpfs` so it could be file-system sensitive. Also, the spec  states *An implementation MAY choose not to support trashing in some of these cases (notably on network resources and removable devices).*

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of some property of the filesystem or its top directory that would be checked by Dolphin and PCManFM and make them decide not use top-dir trash dirs. Something like the sticky bit which according to the spec must be checked for `.Trash`, but the spec doesn't say this for `$topdir/.Trash-$uid` dirs (which are created by the file manager anyway). @xenoid